# In microservices, should a data be store in one service or duplicated across services?

Tags: node.js, database-design, architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

I have a `Scheduler` service which allows me to add scheduled tasks. This service merely saves in its database the schedule time and endpoint to call when the task is triggered.

For example, there is a `Payment` service and a `EmailReminder` service. The `Payment` service can add a scheduled task of recurring payment to the `Scheduler` service. The `EmailReminder` service can add an email reminder task to the `Scheduler` service. When the tasks are triggered in the `Scheduler` service, they will be marked as `done` and sent to an endpoint of the respective services to process the task.

On the frontend, it has to show all the information of the scheduled email reminder task such as the recipient email, email content, and whether it has been done. The frontend will pull most of these information from an API resided in the `EmailReminder` service. That’s simple because all the data that it needs to show in the API from its own database.

However, my dilemma is whether I should keep the `done` status in the database of the `Scheduler` service or to save this status in the respective services’ own database.

#### If status was stored in `Scheduler` service...

If I keep the ‘done’ status in the `Scheduler` service, whenever the other services need to know whether a task is done, they have to make an API call to the `Scheduler` service. In other words, the `EmailReminder` service has to fetch the ‘done’ status from the `Scheduler` service for all the records every time when its API is called from the frontend. I believe this is also going to incur extra time on the overall request. But the pros of doing this is that the database in the `Scheduler` service is the only source of truth for whether a task is done or not.

#### If status was stored in the respective services...

In this case, the `EmailReminder` service doesn't need to make an additional API call to the `Scheduler` service. The information is available in its own database. This would also mean that when there is a change to the `done` status in `Scheduler` service, it has to dispatch an event to inform all services to update their status. The drawback with this, however, is I'm basically having duplicated copies of the same piece of information (the `done` status) in 2 places; the `Scheduler` service and the `EmailReminder` service. There is risk that the data can become inconsistent.

In a microservice architecture like the one I'm having, is it better to store such information in the `Scheduler` service or in the respective services?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should keep that information in both services.

Let's say the `Scheduler` requests the `EmailReminder` to send out e-mail with id #123 and the `EmailReminder` sends out the email and persists a "email #123 sent" state locally, but acknowledgement fails (the `Scheduler` doesn't receive a response or fails to persist the reponse). Now the `Scheduler` have no choice but to repeat the request. But when the `EmailReminder` receives the request it knows via it's own state that the mail was already sent and the service can safely not send the mail, but just respond with acknowledgement - which hopefully works this time.

When the `Scheduler` receives the response it will persist a "scheduled task #123 completed" state locally - and stop repeating the request.

> This would also mean that when there is a change to the done status in Scheduler service, it has to dispatch an event to inform all services to update their status.

How can `Scheduler` change it's doneness, if it's not the `EmailReminder` service telling it, it has been done?

> There is risk that the data can become inconsistent.

Yes, inconsistent data here means that the request needs to be retried.

One thing to note, is that the same problem of inconsistency exists in the `EmailReminder` service itself, as the email can be sent and an error prevent the local state from being updated correctly. So there's always a chance of the email being sent twice ("at least once" delivery, or you could choose "at most once" by changing the state before sending) - but risk is lower this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right dilemma and I do not think there is a perfect answer to this. Every solution would have some trade-off. At some point, it also comes down to the `Fat` event vs `Thin` event.

In the `Fat` event scenario you would have the `Status` information travel along with the message, while in the `Thin` event you would only send the event and not the data.

Let us say, you have many dependent services on your `Scheduler` services. If you choose to fire your event without the additional data (or status information), you may have all those services calling your API asking for the updated `Status` causing additional load on the service. While that may incur a performance cost due do an additional call over the wire, unless you are working on a time-critical application, I do not think it is really an issue. You could also choose to cache the response on the server to avoid the DB call.

If you choose a `Fat` event, then since you are sending the "Status" information along with your event then you would not need the additional API call. It does, however, mean that you would need additional storage to store "Status" in each service. But, storage is a commodity, it is cheap and probably should not be the reason of not using FAT event. There is, of course, a risk here that what if somehow one of the subscribers misses the event. However, Event-Driven architecture comes with those risks, and you need to make your services fault-tolerant of those issues. There are platforms like [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) and [NServiceBus](https://particular.net/nservicebus) that help you to mitigate those risks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I recommend that you don't cache/duplicate data unless you have a reason to.  Cache invalidation is considered [one of the two hard thing in Computer Science](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).  Having downstream services subscribe to events also adds complexity, which adds to overall cost.  Note that I am a *huge* fan of Event Driven Architecture/Messaging--I just believe that you should be judicious in where and when you use it.

In my opinion,

> . . . whenever the other services need to know whether a task is done, they have to make an API call to the Scheduler service.

is not necessarily a negative.

If these calls are very frequent and/or are causing (or likely to cause) performance problems, that is a different story and caching makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

An easy question about collaborative processing. The product produced by the modules should exist in one location, and each module should be responsible for knowing whether or not to process it. In other words, the "done" status is a column of the end product, not any particular service working on it.

Your "service databases" are each service's state, which should be modeled independently of the end product. You've built the process without defining the product's header and storing it separately.

Comment: So, am I right to say that what you meant is that the `done` status should only reside in the database of Scheduler service and not the other services, right? And if the other services want to know if a task is done or not, they make a request to the Scheduler service to look up for it, is this what u mean?

Comment: Yes, the other service produce the done status which is part of the Scheduler's record. However, they should have permission to directly read/write that data to the Scheduler's record, as that record is the product. A transaction system ledger would naturally log each change and by whom before reconciling a balance, if you want to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The `EmailReminder` is the only entity knowing when the e-mail has been sent (i.e. the task is `done`).

Using an event-driven approach, the `EmailReminder` can trigger a `done` event that can be intercepted by all the other actors in the system. In this way, everyone can have a copy of the information. It is good from a performance and resilience perspective, as long as you deal with the drawbacks (defining a master of a specific data set, eventual consistency, and others).

You need to assess whether that is applicable to your system.

Good luck with your project.

Answer (score -1):

In the Microservice architecture, generally,  shared data should only include non-sensitive unique identifier or key only. Microservices should only store data,  which  services require for its processing as defined their bounded context.